# How to unlock in_use table - mysql

Tags: mysql, locking

Use: show open tables where In_use > 0; 
there're 2 tables "In_use". I tried to "REPAIR TABLE" and let it run for hours, but not working. 
Is there any good way to do it?

Comment: first check if you are able to update these 2 tables try to execute a update command...check show full processlist command on same time by super user and check what queries are executing at that time notedown them...and check r u able...also what is the table size....

Comment: There are more than 4.5 million records, but the tables are not wide. every time I tried to delete some records in the tables. The tables will be "In_use" forever. update features works, but I want to delete some records.

Comment: how you are deleting records....you should first fetch primary key of those records you want to delete and then delete based on these ids (primary key)...if you are not using primary key then you can do it based on any indexed int type field.

Comment: Also if there are too many rows for deletion like 10 lacs then you can devide them in small bunch like 50,000 or 25,000 as per your server capacity...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to unlock them explicitly with unlock_tables command. More info is here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html